# joomla calling encoded URL value

Tags: php, joomla

I have a url that gets encoded when serialized with jquery and comes out like this:

```
index.php?city%5B%5D=METROPLOIS&city%5B%5D=GOTHAM
```

Supposed to be index.php?city[]=METROPLOIS&city[]=GOTHAM

On the other end, I'm using joomla to pull down a bunch of variables out of the url

```
$city = JRequest::getVar('city');
```

Now, another user was nice enough to point me to this code in PHP which would get the city variables and then implode them into

```
$cities = $_GET['city'];

$str = "CITY='".implode("' OR CITY='",$city)."'";
```

Where `$cities = $_GET['city'];` is equivalent to `$city = JRequest::getVar('city');`

So, I'm running into a challenge that I don't know how to address.  How to decode the URL in Joomla so that it will recognize `city%5B%5D` as `city[]` or `city`.

I've seen this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php, but that pulls down the URL and puts it into a string.  How would I then tell Joomla to pull variables form that string instead of the URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the url

```
$decoded = urldecode('index.php?city%5B%5D=METROPLOIS&city%5B%5D=GOTHAM');
$query = parse_url($decoded, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
$city = $params['city'];
echo "CITY='".implode("' OR CITY='",$city)."'";
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/0Wnp04QY)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php